# Should I use Friedman test or Mixed Model for my data in R? Nested or not?

Tags: r, mixed-model, large-data, nested-models, friedman-test

I have my ***Response variable*** which is Proportion of Range Exposed to extreme events for terrestrial mammal species in the future. More clearly, it is the **Difference of Proportion of Range Exposed** (DPRE) from historical period to future green gases emission scenarios (it is a measure of the level of increase/decrease of percentage of range exposed): it means that my response variable goes from -1 to 1 (where +1 implies that the range will experience a +100% increase in the proportion of exposure: from 0% in historical period, to 100% in the future scenario).

As said, I am analyzing these differences for all terrestrial mammals (5311 species, across different scenarios and for two time periods, near future (means of 2021-2040) and far future (means of 2081-2100).
So, my ***Explicative variables*** are:

- 3 Scenarios of green gas emissions (Representative Concentration Pathways: **RCP2.6, RCP4.5 and RCP8.5**);
- Time Periods (Near Future and Far Future): **NF and FF**;
- Species: **5311 individuals**.

This means I have a df with 31866 rows, and I want to look for the variables that are more "significative". Here is the lnk to download df (R.code and csv): https://workupload.com/archive/YN3bFSPE. In df there is also the RCP_TP column, which is RCP and Time Period unified, as this composed variable may be the solution instead of the other 2 taken separately.

I am not so expert in statistics , so I'm not sure which of the two suggestions I recieved:

- ***Friedman test*** with Species as blocks (but in which I should somehow do a nested model, with RCPs as groups, nested within TimePeriods; or a sort of two way Friedman, with RCP and TimePeriod as the two different factors).
- ***Linear Mixed Models*** with RCP*TimePeriod as fixed effects, and (TimePeriod | Species ) as random effects.

I run t-test, and all distribution result to be not normal, this is why I was suggested to use Friendman instead of ANOVA; I run pairwise Wilcoxon Rank Sum test and in this case I found significative differences from NF and FF for all RCPs.
I have to say I run 3 Wilcoxon tests, one for every RCP, so maybe a third option would be to create 3 different models, one for every RCP, but this would also go away from the standard analysis of "repated measures" for Friedman test.

**Last consideration**: I have to run Another model, where the ***Response*** variable is the **Difference of Proportion of Subrange Exposed**. In this case, other ***Explicative*** variables are mantained, but in this case analysis is not global but takes in consideration the difference that could be present across 14 IUCN **Biomes**. So every analysis is made across RCPs, for NF and FF and for all Biomes. Should I create and run 14 (biomes) x 3 (RCPs) x 2 (Time Periods) = 84 models, in this case? OR a sort of double nested (Time Periods and Biomes) model?

If necessary I can provide the large dataframe.

Comment: If you can provide the data, then please do so, and you are more likely to receive answers.

Comment: I provided a screenshot of my table, as creating a 31866 rows table was challenging

Comment: Can you post a link to where we can download the data ?An extract doesn't help much

Comment: Here it is: thank you for the help https://workupload.com/archive/YN3bFSPE